# Can't spot the reason behind infinite loop

Tags: c++, flood-fill

I am currently working on a program, that can read a set of coordinates from a file forming a contour and then fill it out using the flood fill algorithm.

It seems that the code below runs in an infinite loop, but i can't seem to spot why.

Help or advice is much appreciated :-)

```
    /* Flood fill */
    TargetColour = 0.0;
    NewColour = 2.0;
    starting_point = 0+slice;

    //Create queue
    queue < int > MyQue;
    //Insert first point into the queue
    MyQue.push(starting_point);

    //While loop for iterating over the nodes.
    while (!MyQue.empty()){
        //Take out the front element
        Node = MyQue.front();
        MyQue.pop();
        tmpSlice[Node] = NewColour;

        //Define the Node directions
        WestNode = Node-1;
        EastNode = Node+1;
        NorthNode = Node-sizes[1];
        SouthNode = Node+sizes[2];


        //East Node
        if (slab[EastNode] == TargetColour && floor((Node-sizes[1]*sizes[2]*floor(Node/(sizes[1]*sizes[2])))/sizes[1]) == floor((EastNode-sizes[1]*sizes[2]*floor(EastNode/(sizes[1]*sizes[2])))/sizes[1])){
            MyQue.push(EastNode);
        }
        //West Node
        if (slab[WestNode] == TargetColour && floor((Node-sizes[1]*sizes[2]*floor(Node/(sizes[1]*sizes[2])))/sizes[1]) == floor((WestNode-sizes[1]*sizes[2]*floor(WestNode/(sizes[1]*sizes[2])))/sizes[1])){
            MyQue.push(WestNode);
        }
        //North Node
        if (slab[NorthNode] == TargetColour && floor(Node / (sizes[1]*sizes[2])) == floor(NorthNode / (sizes[1]*sizes[2]))){
            MyQue.push(NorthNode);
        }
        //South Node
        if (slab[SouthNode] == TargetColour && floor(Node / (sizes[1]*sizes[2])) == floor(SouthNode / (sizes[1]*sizes[2]))){
            MyQue.push(SouthNode);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does this code have to do with medical datasets?

Comment: What happens if you feed the data a *very small* dataset?  (Perhaps a triangle).  Does it terminate then?  Are you sure you haven't got an infinite loop rather than a performance problem?

Comment: A `vector<vector<double>` is almost always a terrible data structure.  Try `typedef array<double,3> Coordinate; vector<Coordinate>` instead.  (It will be *vastly* more cache friendly, and use about 1/3 the memory).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews - The program is used to run over PET Scans, and i thought that because it did not terminate it was because of poor performance and the large dataset.

Comment: Are you sure the tmpSlice is actually writing the new colour to the target? Also, it's not a very efficient algorithm. You get large numbers of duplicated points in the queue doing it that way.

Comment: @MartinBonner Thanks for the suggested array! I think you are right that the while loop is an infinite loop (i let it run for 1.5 million iterations). I still don't know what is causing the loop to be infinite but i will hopefully find out.

Comment: How many data points are you processing? 1.5 million iterations might not be that much, since you are generating a lot of duplicates in the queue

Comment: Before assigning `NewColour`, you could check `if (tmpSlice[Node] == NewColour) continue;` in order to avoid duplicate visits with additional neighbor visits in queue

Comment: @grek40, its 34 slides of data with each ranging from 100 to 400 coordinates of type (x,y,z)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm partly sure that your algorithm is actually terminating, but only after a very long time (assuming there is enough memory for the queue). I'd need more details on the values of `sizes` to be completely sure.

Lets play a little 3x3 example field and assume that the whole `floor((Node-sizes[1]*sizes[2]*floor(Node/(sizes[1]*sizes[2])))/sizes[1])` is just a boundary check (what is it?).

Field (numbers are the position names):

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Assume `starting_point = 1`

1. MyQue = { 1 }

   - visit 1, add 2 and 4 to MyQue
2. MyQue = { 2, 4 }

   - visit 2, add 3 and 5 to MyQue
3. MyQue = { 4, 3, 5 }

   - visit 4, add 5 and 7 to MyQue
4. MyQue = { 3, 5, 5, 7 }

   - visit 3, add 6 to MyQue
5. MyQue = { 5, 5, 7, 6 }

   - visit 5, add 6 and 8 to MyQue
6. MyQue = { 5, 7, 6, 6, 8 }

   - visit 5, add 6 and 8 to MyQue
7. MyQue = { 7, 6, 6, 8, 6, 8 }

   - visit 7, add 8 to MyQue
8. MyQue = { 6, 6, 8, 6, 8, 8 }

   - visit 6, add 9 to MyQue
9. MyQue = { 6, 8, 6, 8, 8, 9 }

   - visit 6, add 9 to MyQue
10. MyQue = { 8, 6, 8, 8, 9, 9 }

    - visit 8, add 9 to MyQue
11. MyQue = { 6, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9 }

    - visit 6, add 9 to MyQue
12. MyQue = { 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9 }

    - visit 8, add 9 to MyQue
13. MyQue = { 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9 }

    - visit 8, add 9 to MyQue
14. MyQue = { 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9 }

    - visit 9
15. MyQue = { 9, 9, 9, 9, 9 }

    - visit 9
16. MyQue = { 9, 9, 9, 9 }

    - visit 9
17. MyQue = { 9, 9, 9 }

    - visit 9
18. MyQue = { 9, 9 }

    - visit 9
19. MyQue = { 9 }

    - visit 9

I hope this illustrates how the algorithm is going to repeat the same thing very often even for a small field - this effect will increase for bigger field sizes.

So what you can do is ensure that each node is only queued once. I think the evaluation order doesn't really matter, so instead of a `queue` you can use a `set` to store the working set. This will ensure that each number is only queued once at the same time.

You can also combine queue and set so you keep evaluation order.

```
set < int > marker;
queue < int > MyQue;

// ... replace later in code
// MyQue.push(SomeNode);
// by
if (marker.insert(SomeNode).second) {
    MyQue.push(SomeNode);
}
```

Edit: changed the if condition a bit. `marker.insert(SomeNode).second` will be `true` if `SomeNode` was inserted and `false` if `SomeNode` was already part of the set.

Comment: Thanks for the really awesome and understandable example made it a whole lot easier to understand and i think you are correct about where the problem lies.

Comment: For clarification the whole floor is for boundary check and the sizes are 400 * 400. After editing the code to match your changes the code runs for 160001 iterations, and produces a Segmentation fault (core dumped). The obvious thing is i have only allocated a 400*400 array but it seems to surpass that.

Comment: Well your whole floor thing made me very suspicious but my head started to hurt when I tried to understand what you do there, so I stopped :P. If you think you need this kind of calculation, just add a boundary check (regarding the array index, not your logical boundaries) before your `push` and break if boundaries are violated. Then look at all your values and understand why it's calculating something wrong.